# Kullback-Leibler divergence based kernel

Tags: probability-theory, numerical-methods, machine-learning, information-theory

I'm looking at this paper: ["A Kullback-Leibler Divergence Based Kernel for SVM Classification in Multimedia Applications"](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.58.3845). The author suggests using the kernel function for two distributions $p$ and $q$: $k(p,q)= \exp (-a (D_{KL}(p,q) + D_{KL}(q,p)))$, where $a>0$ and $D_{KL}$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between $p$ and $q$. But it's not obvious from this paper that this kernel is positive definite.
How it can be proved that the kernel is positive definite?

Also, it's well known that $\exp (-a (D_{KL}(p,q) + D_{KL}(q,p)))$ can be positive definite if and only if $(D_{KL}(p,q) + D_{KL}(q,p))$ is a negative definite kernel. How can one proof that fact?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a kernel of the form: $K(x,y) = \exp^{-a(M(x,y))}$, all is needed is for $M(x,y)$ to be a valid [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29). So all that is required is to prove that the Symmetrised K-L Divergence (call it $KLS(p,q)$) is a valid metric.

For all $x, y, z \in X$, this function is required to satisfy the following conditions:

1. $d(x, y) \geq 0$     (non-negativity)
2. $d(x, y) = 0 \iff x = y$     (identity of indiscernibles. Note that condition 1 and 2 together produce positive definiteness)
3. $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$     (symmetry)
4. $d(x, z) ≤ d(x, y) + d(y, z)$     (subadditivity / triangle inequality).

1 and 2 hold for each of $KL(p,q)$ and $KL(q,p)$ and therefore hold for $KLS(p,q)$.
3 holds trivially.

However 4 does not hold:

Counter example
Consider
a=[0.3 0.3 0.4]
b=[0.25 0.35 0.4]
c=[0.16 0.33 0.51]

we have

$KL(a||b)+KL(b||a)+KL(b||c)+KL(c||b)-[KL(a||c)+KL(c||a)]\approx -0.0327<0$

So $KLS(p,q)$ is not a valid metric.

Unless I've missed something, I do not believe that their kernels are necessarily positive definite - I'm assuming that it wasn't discussed in the review process otherwise I'd expect to see it discussed in the paper. Practically, it may not be a problem, as for their real world examples the matrices may have been (at least close to) SPSD, and with appropriate regularisation (even just adding a small constant to the diagonal) the algorithms should still work. There is also some work in solving SVMs for indefinite kernels, see e.g. [Training SVM with Indeﬁnite Kernels](http://icml2008.cs.helsinki.fi/papers/531.pdf) or [Analysis of SVM with Indefinite Kernels](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips22/NIPS2009_0135.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120312022523/http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips22/NIPS2009_0135.pdf), [CiteSeerX](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/doc_view/pid/09b6cc51fe70c2d0a907809714617d47cf4966fe)) so all is not lost even if the kernels are indefinite.

It's interesting that their results are so much better than using Fisher kernels - in my experience too, Fisher kernels don't work that well - so this is potentially a nice way of combining generative and discriminative methods. Let us know how you get on if you get round to using them!!

Comment: "If you have a kernel of the form: (,)=exp−((,)), all is needed is for (,) to be a valid metric." -- this is neither necessary nor sufficient. What is needed is for M^{1/2} do be "Hilbertian metric" i.e. M(x,y)=||f(x)-f(y)||^2 If it is, then K is basically RBF, and is valid. Converse is harder but follows from "known" things.

Comment: Observe that ||x||^2 is not a metric, so being a metric is not necessary.  Moreover, there exist metrics d such that d^{1/2} is not Hilbertian (there are such on spaces as small as 6 points); for such metrics exp(-a d) will not be a valid kernel at least for some of the a. Thus being a metric is also not sufficient.

Comment: Square root of Jensen-Shannon divergence is a Hilbertian metric by result of Fuglede and Topsøe (though I don't know a simple proof). For symmetrized KL as above the unswer is unclear (maybe even unknown?).